# Tempfile.new vs. File.open on Heroku

Tags: ruby, file, heroku

I'm capturing/creating user entered text into files from my app, attempting to temporarily store them in my Heroku tmp directory, then upload them to a cloud service such as Google Drive.

In using Tempfile I can successfully upload, but when using File.open I get the following error when attempting to upload:

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (1 for 0))
```

The error is on the call:

```
@client.upload_file_by_folder_id(save_path, @folder_id)
```

Where @client is a session with the cloud service, save_path is the location of the attached file for upload and @folder_id is the folder they should go into.

When I use Tempfile.new I am successful in doing so:

```
    tempfile = Tempfile.new([final_filename, '.txt'], Rails.root.join('tmp','text-temp'))
    tempfile.binmode
    tempfile.write msgbody
    tempfile.close
    save_path = tempfile.path
    upload_file = @client.upload_file_by_folder_id(save_path, @folder_id)
    tempfile.unlink
```

File.open code is:

```
path = 'tmp/text-temp'
filename = "#{final_filename}.txt"
save_path = Rails.root.join(path, filename)      
File.open(save_path, 'wb') do |file|
  file.write(msgbody)
  file.close
end
upload_file = @client.upload_file_by_folder_id(save_path, @folder_id)
File.delete(save_path)
```

Could it be that the File.path is a string, and Tempfile.path is the full path (but not as a string)?  When I put out each, they look identical.

I'd like to use File as I don't want to change the filename of the existing attachments I'm uploading, whereas Tempfile appends to the filename.

Any and all assistance is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order for it to work using File, I needed to set the save_path to a string:

```
save_path.to_s
```